# Epdm api getfolder path from folderId

Tags: solidworks

I'm coding an EPDM Addin in C# (IEdmAddIn5)
This addin add command on the contex menu.

From this command, I want the path of the selected folder. But I can't only get the folderId. via (ref Array ppoData)

Is there a way to get directly the folder path ? Or is there a way to get Folder Path from Folder Id ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To access the folder path, use the LocalPath property on the IEdmFolder5 object.  The local path could vary on different clients due to where the vault view is created.

```
IEdmFolder5 folder = vault.GetObject((int)EdmObjectType.EdmObject_Folder, folderId) as IEdmFolder5;
string path = folder.LocalPath;
```